# share internet as client to other client by intermediary server in nodejs net module

Tags: node.js, pipe, vpn

Suppose we have cloud server as intermediary server and we have two client.

client2 want to use client1's internet through cloud intermediary server, both client does not have public IP.

client2 will access cloud server as proxy server in firefox and internet should work.

How do we achieve this in node JS

cloud server code:

```
const net = require('net');
const user1Server = net.createServer();
const user3Server = net.createServer();

const user1Port = 3001; // Port User 1 will connect to
const user3Port = 3003; // Port User 3 will connect to

const user1Sockets = [];
const user3Sockets = [];

// Create a server to listen for connections from User 1
user1Server.on('connection',(user1Socket) => {
  console.log('User 1 connected');
  user1Sockets.push(user1Socket);

  user1Socket.on('data', (data) => {
    //console.log('User 1 received:', data.toString());

    // Process data or perform any necessary operations here

    // Forward data to all User 3 sockets
    user3Sockets.forEach((user3Socket) => {
      //user3Socket.write(data);
      user3Socket.pipe(user1Socket)
       user1Socket.pipe(user3Socket)
    });
  });

  user1Socket.on('end', () => {
    console.log('User 1 disconnected');
    const index = user1Sockets.indexOf(user1Socket);
    if (index !== -1) {
      user1Sockets.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });

  user1Socket.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('User 1 error:', err);
  });
});

user1Server.listen(user1Port, () => {
  console.log('User 1 server listening on port', user1Port);
});

// Create a server to listen for connections from User 3
user3Server.on("connection",(user3Socket) => {
  console.log('User 3 connected');
  user3Sockets.push(user3Socket);

  user3Socket.on('data', (data) => {
    //console.log('User 3 received:', data.toString());

    data2 = `CONNECT freeforonline.com:443 HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0
    Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
    Connection: keep-alive
    Host: freeforonline.com:443`
    // Process data or perform any necessary operations here

    let isTLSConnection = data.toString().indexOf("CONNECT") !== -1;
    if(isTLSConnection)
    {
      console.log('-------------')
      user3Socket.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n");
          // Forward data to all User 1 sockets

    }
    else{
      console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@')
      //user1Sockets[0].write(data);
    }

    
    user3Socket.pipe(user1Sockets[0])
    user1Sockets[0].pipe(user3Socket)

    // user1Sockets.forEach((user1Socket) => {
    //   user1Socket.write(data);
      
   
    // });


  });

  user3Socket.on('end', () => {
    console.log('User 3 disconnected');
    const index = user3Sockets.indexOf(user3Socket);
    if (index !== -1) {
      user3Sockets.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });

  user3Socket.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('User 3 error:', err);
  });
});

user3Server.listen(user3Port, () => {
  console.log('User 3 server listening on port', user3Port);
});
```

and client server code

```
const net = require('net');

const user2Host = '127.0.0.1'; // Replace with User 2's IP address or hostname
const user1Port = 3001; // Port that User 2 is listening on for User 1

const user1Socket = net.createConnection({ host: user2Host, port: user1Port });

user1Socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to User 2 (Intermediary Server)');
});

user1Socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Received data from User 2 (Intermediary Server):', data.toString());
    let isTLSConnection = data.toString().indexOf("CONNECT") !== -1;
    let serverPort = 80;
    let serverAddress;
    //console.log('received data : ' + data.toString());
    if (isTLSConnection) {
        console.log('-------------')
        serverPort = 443;

        serverAddress = data
            .toString()
            .split("CONNECT")[1]
            .split(" ")[1]
            .split(":")[0];
    } else {
        console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@')
        serverAddress = data.toString().split("Host: ")[1].split("\r\n")[0];
    }

    // Creating a connection from proxy to destination server
    let ipClient = net.createConnection(
        {
            host: serverAddress,
            port: serverPort,
        },
        () => {
            console.log("Proxy to server set up")

        }
    );

    if (isTLSConnection) {
        user1Socket.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n");
        //connectedClients[0].write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n");
        
    } else {
        ipClient.write(data);
        //connectedClients[0].write(data);
       
    }
    ipClient.pipe(user1Socket);
    //user1Socket.write(ipClient)
   // user1Socket.pipe(ipClient);
    

    // Process data received from User 2 as needed
});

user1Socket.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected from User 2 (Intermediary Server)');
});

user1Socket.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('User 1 error:', err);
});

// You can send data to User 2 (Intermediary Server) using user1Socket.write()
```

in this way i am not able to established connection

I already trayed client to client connection but not working, some issue is facing while there is not TLS request